# Android: Gradle imports failing to resolve

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build

I am trying to install with gradle this library:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6652

It NEEDS jitpack in the gradle:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

All fixes I have found result in me having to replace the above with maven.google.

I need to use jitpack.

The errors i get:

> Failed to resolve com.android.support.appcompat.

Answer (score 2):

Add `https://maven.google.com` or `google()` to your repositories  block.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

**OR**

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can avoid putting url for the maven of google by just replacing it with google() :)

Comment: Thats for sure .

Answer (score 0):

Add AppCompact lib as below:

In the app.gradle, add appCompact lib:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"
```

Add google() as below:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you should update your android studio as well gradle. But anyways,  or, you can use a url if that's what you cannot afford.